# ListView layout find view

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, xamarin

In Xamarin, I am wanting to create a Custom Row Layout for a ListView.

Here is my code:

```
items = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
items.Add(new Tuple<string,string>("Email 1", "me@me.com"));

ListView lst = new ListView (this.ApplicationContext);
ListAdapter = new List_Adapter(this, items);
lst.Adapter = ListAdapter;
```

Here is the GetView code:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    var view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem2, null);

    var item = GetItem(position);

    view.FindViewById<TextView> (Android.Resource.Id.Text1).Text = item.Item1;
    view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text2).Text = item.Item2;

    return view;
}
```

I have created my own TextViewForListViewLayout.xml file in the Resources->Layout folder. How can I use this TextView Layout for this TextView:

```
view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text2).Text = item.Item2;
```

I cannot reference it. It's name is TextViewForListViewLayout.

Can I have some help with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the Android from code.

```
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    var view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.TextViewForListViewLayout, null);
    var item = GetItem(position);
    view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.Text1).Text = item.Item1;
    view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text2).Text = item.Item2;
    return view;
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error: The name 'Resource' does not exist in the current context

Comment: This activity is not the main activity...What do I need to do?